# C# parameter passing abnormality

Tags: c#, list, parameters, reference, instance

so I was just coding along when I had this weird behavior happening:

```
public NumPadComboListener(List<String> master)
{

  _listen = new MultiKeyListener(false);
  List<String> seq = master;
  seq.Add("NumPad0");
  _listen.registerNewKeySequence(0, seq);
  seq.Remove("NumPad0");
  seq.Add("NumPad1");
  _listen.registerNewKeySequence(1, seq);
  seq.Remove("NumPad1");
  seq.Add("NumPad2");
  _listen.registerNewKeySequence(2, seq);
  seq.Remove("NumPad2");
  seq.Add("NumPad3");
  _listen.registerNewKeySequence(3, seq);
  seq.Remove("NumPad3");
  seq.Add("NumPad4");
  _listen.registerNewKeySequence(4, seq);
  seq = null;

}
```

and it just puts inside a list of lists.
But weirdly enough the list at the end consists of 5 copies of the last version of "seq" passed in.

```
elem 1, elem2, NumPad4
elem 1, elem2, NumPad4
elem 1, elem2, NumPad4
elem 1, elem2, NumPad4
elem 1, elem2, NumPad4
```

How can I pass the lists as seperate instances instead of references like it seems to be right now?

Comment: What is the purpose of `master` in this scenario?  To copy a list you would create a new list, and pass an `IEnumerable` (or list) as into its constructor.  `var seq = new List<string>(master)`, seq is now a copy of what was in master, instead of just referencing it.

Comment: Code above gives me creeps in many ways... that aside `_listen.registerNewKeySequence(0, new List<string> { "NumPad0" });`

Comment: those comments ignore, that i need to add a string to the list (and thats not possible as far as i know, inside the calling parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I pass the lists as separate instances instead of references like it seems to be right now?

You have to explicitly create an entirely new list, and pass in a reference to that new list.  You can use `ToList` to do this with very little code, even though behind the scenes it'll still need to copy every single item over to a new list that is created.

You'll then need to alter all of your method calls accordingly:

```
_listen.registerNewKeySequence(0, seq.ToList());
```

If you don't want this method to mutate the `master` list passed in then you'll *also* need to make a copy of the list itself (and not a reference to it) at the start of the method and assign that new list to `seq`.

Comment: Thanks! 
I didn't realize that a list had a ToList() method. Kinda useless until now ^^ Also this works, for anyone wondering.

Comment: Doing `seq.ToList()` could be completely pointless, unless you know what `registerNewKeySequence` does.  If `registerNewKeySequence` modifies the incoming list, then passing in a list without a reference would be tantamount to passing in a bogus argument.

Comment: if you want to know:  (due to character limitation)

http://pastebin.com/K803svZE

Comment: The `ToList` method is actually an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, quite often it's used to materialize a result-set from ORMs like Entity Framework.  As for your method, it would be easier to understand the intent if it accepted `IEnumerable<T>` and did a copy inside of the method.  Passing in `IEnumerable<T>` implies that the parameter is not modified.

Comment: @Matthew The question is specifically asking for how to pass in separate copies of the instances instead of copies of the reference to the list, which is what he's currently doing.  If he only wanted to pass copies of the reference then his code would already be working.